# Mongodb query does not the show the expect result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

**I am using node and express server to run the mongoDb. For connection and schema I am using mongoose. i successfully connect the database and able to post the data by using postman but problem is it does not show the expected query. Mongodb returns me only the id not the query which is name and description**

**Here is models**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const form = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const formSubmit = mongoose.model("formSubmit", form);
module.exports = formSubmit;
```

**This is my express server**

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
const formSubmit = require("./models");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

mongoose
  .connect(
    "url",
    {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected!"))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

//get method
app.get("/show", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const entrries = await formSubmit.find();
    res.json(entrries);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

//post method

app.post("/post", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const logs = new formSubmit(req.body);
    const entry = await logs.save();
    res.json(entry);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(422);
    }
    next(error);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to see the mongodb database query?

Comment: yes. When I post name and description value but in Mongodb atlas I just  see only id. It does not store name and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you don't correctly save the documents to the collection, so when you retrieve them only _id fields display.

To be able to read request body, you need to add [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) middleware to your server.js.

```
 app.use(express.json());
```